# C# for loop with already defined iterator

Tags: c#

I want to make a loop using an already-defined iterator.

At present I am using

```
int i;
while (i<10)
{
    Console.Writeline(i);
    i++;
}
```

This is ugly because someone else might later remove the i++. If it is separated from the while statement by a large block of code, it will not be clear what it is for.

What I'd really like is something like

```
int i;
for (i<10; i++)
{
    Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

This makes it clear what's going on, but it's not valid C#.

The best I've come up with so far is

```
int i;
for (int z; i<10; i++)
{
    Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

But that's ugly. Does C# give me an elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you don't *have* to have anything inside the first part of the loop:

```
for (; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Is that what you're looking for? Personally I would typically *try* to avoid this sort of situation anyway though - I find it pretty unusual to want a loop without a new variable.

Comment: And for extra minimalism, try `for (;;)` for an infinite loop (instead of `while (true)`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I am iterating on someone else's variable, so I can't create it here.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an empty first part of the "for":

```
int i;
for (; i<10; i++)
{
    Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign the variable to itself in the first part of the loop like this:

```
int i;
for (i=i; i<10; i++)
{
    Console.Writeline(i);
}
```

I find that it's slightly clearer than leaving the first part of the loop blank, however Visual Studio will give you a warning "Assignment made to the same variable; did you mean to assign it to something else?"